# Can we run a mysql query through command prompt in windows?

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql5

Can we run MySQL query from windows command prompt? If so, how can we do that and process the query result through command prompt?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use [mysql — the MySQL command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) with '--execute=statement' or '-e statement' option.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the MySQL client for windows and then use that for sending commands to a server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql.html

You can use the following type of format for commands

mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab

or

shell> mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name

Then type an SQL statement, end it with “;”, \g, or \G and press Enter.

Answer (score 3):

practical example of @devarts recommendation
enter your user & password & Database

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD  -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' -- list databases

mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD  MyDATABASE -e 'SHOW TABLES;' -- list tables in MyDATABASE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes, We can access whole DB from command line.  
1. Connect to DB (no space between -p and password)
    mysql -h <host> -u <username> -p<password>
2. Now we can check how many db we have
   show databases;
or many more commands and even we can execute quires through command line. For more command details http://g2pc1.bu.edu/~qzpeng/manual/MySQL%20Commands.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Windows:

- Open window console  Run CMD
- type/copy: mysql -h hostname -u UserName -pPassWordTogether dbNAme -e"select * from table;" > D:/file.csv
- Easy and fast.

Good Luck.