# setting a c-shell variable to a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

i have written a c-shell script to connect to a database. This already works just fine and i now want to invoke an sql script to read and print ALL the values in a cetrain table. As of now this is how my script looks

```
#!/bin/csh 


set MYSQL=${MYSQL_HOME}/mysql
${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER}
```

where CLEDBUSER is set as an environment variable like so - CLEADBUSER=-uusername -ppassword -Ddatabasename

i am able to run the script and connect to the database. When i runt he script it gives me the msql pront awaiting the next command. So i added to the script a variable that contains the (SELECT) statement to query the database. Now my script looks like this

```
#!/bin/csh 


set MYSQL=${MYSQL_HOME}/mysql

set SELECTER="SELECT * FROM TB_EARTH_UI;"

${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER} ${SELECTER}
```

the problem is it doesnt return me all the rows and columsn but it returns me a listing of avaiable commands in mysql promt and default options and also vairables and boolean options. Why is my SELECT statement not getting read?

Comment: in other words when you have already connected to the database via a c-shell script can you also read and execute sql commands at the same time through the same c-shell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we run a mysql query through command prompt in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444359/can-we-run-a-mysql-query-through-command-prompt-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL client (`mysql`) expects SQL instructions on its standard input (e.g. your keyboard, when invoking from the shell).

You could do: [edit: please ignore, this one is off-topic]

```
${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER} < text_file_of_sql_statements.sql
```

or

```
${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER} << EOF
  ${SELECTER}
  # you can add other litteral SQL statements here, or more variables containing SQL statements
EOF
```

or

```
${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER} --execute="${SELECTER}"
```

[edit]

I totally misunderstood the OP's question. I didn't get it that he was trying to execute SQL statements from a variable. I have edited the above options (thank you outis). Here is another variation:

```
echo ${SELECTER} | ${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER}
```

Also, the `--skip-column-names` option could make it easier for you to parse the output.

Comment: use a text file of sql statements is there any need to declare a variable that holds an sql string? why would i have to use a .sql file to hold my select statement? and also what does SELECT 1 stand for?

Comment: ok i defined a SELECT*FROM my table in a separate sql file and it worked fine and this worked fine

Comment: so does this mean i cannot use direct SQL statements assigned to a vairable in my c-shell script?

Comment: @rambokayambo I am so sorry, I totally misunderstood your question. The third option, edited by outis, is the only one that should fulfill your need.